# Custom PO fields are not updated in EXIT_SAPMM06E_013

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I'm trying to update a customer field in table EKPO when transaction ME22N is used. The custom field's value has to be derived from the item's Confirmations data (EKES). I've extended EKPO by adding a field ZZTEST to CI_EKPODB.

I've added the following code in FM EXIT_SAPMM06E_013 to set the values of the custom field in internal table XEKPO.

```
  LOOP AT xekpo[] ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_ekpo>).

    <fs_ekpo>-zztest  = 'TEST OK'.

  ENDLOOP.
```

The code is called and the internal table is correctly updated. However, the value of ZZTEST is not updated in the database (table EKPO). The other standard values changed in ME22N are correctly updated in the DB though.

Other BADIs I have tried:

- ME_PURCHDOC_POSTED: same problem, the custom field is not updated
- ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST: confirmation data is not accessible because of note 2567839

TL;DR: I'm looking for a BADI / User exit that would allow me to update a PO's custom field by deriving its value from confirmation data. Reading confirmation data from the database is not possible because the currently edited PO might not be committed yet. Please help.

Comment: Can you try changing the yekpo table in the FM (instead of (xekpo)? I am not sure, and can't try it now, but x.... is used like importing parameter and y.... like exporting (however both are tables parameters of the FM)

Comment: In fact, `EXIT_SAPMM06E_013` is not to update the standard tables (standard or custom fields), but custom tables only. You must use other function modules, please refine your question.

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai I tried but it didn't work. (XEKPO holds new values and YEKPO hold old values).

Comment: @SandraRossi Very interesting, thanks. May I ask where you can get this information ? I could not find much documentation. I've tried two other BADIs: ME_PURCHDOC_POSTED and ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST. The first one also doesn't update the customer field in the DB. The second one doesn't expose confirmation data, which I need to determine the value of my customer field.

Comment: Official documentation in `SMOD` (`MM06E005`): "If you wish to update your own tables, you can invoke function module EXIT_SAPMM06E_013" + check in SAP programs for confirmation.

Comment: Thanks. I've rephrased my question to include other possible BADIS.

Comment: use `ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST` for that, here is the sample https://blogs.sap.com/2013/06/11/po-item-modification-using-badi-meprocesspocust/

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in EXIT_SAPMM06E_018:

```
FUNCTION EXIT_SAPMM06E_018.

      INCLUDE ZXM06U40.

ENDFUNCTION.
```

In include `ZXM06U40` add the code:

```
MOVE-CORRESPONDING ci_ekpodb TO e_ci_ekpo.
e_ci_update = 'X'.
```

`EKPO_CI` (Structure: Customer Inlude for Field Transport to Item Subscreen) includes the append structure `CI_EKPODB` (Customer append structure purchase items).

This should lead to the the database table update with values for the custom field.

Note also that the screen fields are to be created with reference to ekpo_ci.